# buildozer is showing error during apk build

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

I was trying to build an apk with buildozer.
The application was written in kivymd.
It works good in linux environment.but when try to debug with buildozer it shows the following error.

The error log that occured in the terminal during the buid is:

```
[INFO]:    Building jpeg for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/jpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/jpeg
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 216, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
File "/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/jpeg/__init__.py", line 31, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.cmake, '-G', 'Unix Makefiles',
File "/home/mohanraj/sudoku/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 3581, in __getattr__
    return self.__env[name]
File "/home/mohanraj/sudoku/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 3378, in __getitem__
    raise CommandNotFound(k)
sh.CommandNotFound: cmake
# Command failed: /home/mohanraj/sudoku/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy==1.11.1,git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git,pillow,pygments --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/mohanraj-Lenovo-E41-25:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1715,unix/mohanraj-Lenovo-E41-25:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1715'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '1.45.1'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL = 'true'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1616'
#     BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/mohanraj/Desktop/temp'
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'mohanraj'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/code'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/mohanraj'
#     USERNAME = 'mohanraj'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/mohanraj/sudoku'
#     DISABLE_WAYLAND = '1'
#     GIT_ASKPASS = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '68bcfaf05ad84b128b6efb0db55b7e21'
#     MANAGERPID = '1432'
#     CHROME_DESKTOP = 'code-url-handler.desktop'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'mohanraj'
#     VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE = '/run/user/1000/snap.code/vscode-git-5a8917b5b6.sock'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '2'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/snap.code'
#     PS1 = ('(sudoku) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
'\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN = '/snap/code/33/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:38672'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/mohanraj/sudoku/bin:/home/mohanraj/.local/bin:/home/mohanraj/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '2173'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'vscode'
#     _ = '/home/mohanraj/sudoku/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/mohanraj/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I dont know what makes the error and how to solve it .Is there any way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have `cmake` installed. Try `sudo -H apt install cmake`.